# Does IE8 behave differently between different OS versions?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Greetings all.

I'm rolling out a website for a client after having tested it on IE7-IE8 on WinXP (and IE6 on W2K).  Strangely, the client is reporting odd behavior from his IE8 browser which I would only normally expect from IE6.  I am using an HTML5 doctype AND I am using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` so I would expect IE8 Best Standards behavior, and this is my experience on XP.  One clear difference is that the client is using Win7 SP1.  Is this a red herring, or do I need to test every operating system too?

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to the client using zoom: 120% on IE8 on Win7 SP1.  Does this trigger quirks mode?  I can't reproduce this on IE8 on WinXP (also at zoom: 120%). =/

Comment: oh, yeah... Zoom is terrible. No-one tests for it (is it even possible to test every possible zoom size in every browser and OS?), and it does cause some really weird glitches. If your client routinely browses at 120% zoom, then he'll have encountered a lot of sites that look broken. If my experience is anything to go by, it's going to be virtually impossible to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sort of odd behaviour is being reported? You may have issues unrelated to the rendering engine.

The main suspect for me is that Win7 will have different default fonts to WinXP (eg Calibri instead of Ariel), so if you've got a layout which fits perfectly for the XP fonts, you may get some layout gremlins on a platform where those fonts aren't available. Calibri is quite similar to Ariel visually, but does have significantly different metrics, so if your layout is tight, you may find your site suffers from some unexpected word-wrapping or element widths.

This will also be the case in other operating systems that don't supply the default Windows fonts (ie MacOS, Linux, though of course, they won't be using IE).

If this does turn out to be your issue, then in theory you could use the CSS `@font-face` to get around this problem, by providing a downloadable font for use on your page directly in your stylesheets. Sadly however, although the various browsers in use at the moment all support this feature, they require the fonts to be in a variety of formats, which can make it quite hard to implement in practice.

An easier and more practical solution to the problem would be simply to test with both fonts, and design the page in such a way that it looks okay in either.

In general, it is a good idea to test in all OS/browser combinations that you expect the site to be used with. Tools like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) are good for testing multiple versions of IE on a single machine. If you can't test all browser/OS combinations yourself, then I would recommend using a service like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/), which will email you screenshots of your site, as loaded in pretty much every browser and OS you can imagine (and quite a few that you probably can't!).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The issues are layout-related, not font related.  I have used BrowserShots, I find them expensive (but useful!).

Comment: I have seen some fairly dramatic layout issues that were caused by font issues, so I'd still suggest checking this out, especially if your layout is using floats. Also, Browsershots does have a paid service, but the basic service is free, as long as you only ask for a few browsers at a time, and don't mind waiting a bit for the results.

Comment: Thank you. I see you've found the cause of the problem is Zoom. I can't believe I didn't think of that, as it has given me plenty of headaches as well. Hope you manage to work out a solution.

Comment: I think the customer may also be forcing this site into Quirks Mode with their settings at Tools -> Compatibility View Settings because their previous website required it.  So, no matter how much I use the right doctype and/or meta properties I use, half the company is going to be looking at it broken.  Seriously, what were MS thinking when they invented Compatibility Mode in the first place, and secondly, why give the clients the ability to force it on?  Harumph!